# how to fix parse error in lollipop while installing apk

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio

I have an application which will download the other apks from our server and install it one by one.
This works fine in versions lower than lollipop 5.0 , but in case of lollipop devices it is giving parse error.
I have also checked the option of installing apk from unknown sources in device.
the  detailed warnings in logcat while installing apk is :

Zip: 2 extraneous bytes at the end of the central directory

W/zipro(5776): Error opening archive /data/local/tmp/XYZ.apk: Invalid file

D/asset(5776): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/XYZ.apk'

W/DefContainer(5776): Failed to parse package at /data/local/tmp/XYZ.apk: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException:
 Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/XYZ.apk

The things I tried and results are as follows,

1.Create fresh new apk and push it via adb into device and try to install -  **Install successfull.**

2.After that upload that same apk to server , download it from browser[ not through application ]-**failed “[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]**

3.I have implemented the MD5 checksum for validating the apk download , checksum is also fine.

4.If I again sign the downloaded apk or zip align the apk [ Effectively repackage apk ] and try to install -**Install successfull.**

Please help me , how to fix this issue.

permissions in Manifest :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally , the issue got fixed !!. Actually the issue was with the server from which I was downloading the apps.There were some .jars needed to be updated on server side which fixed the issue.Hence, the lesson I learned is always be double sure of the backed before diving deep into android framework level.

Comment: im having the same problem, which jars need to be updated?

Comment: At Server side , there was an implementation of multi-part download using spring. So some version upgrade had solved the issue. Dont know the exact version or specifics.